# creating numpy structured arrays from columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

If I want to create a numpy array with `dtype = [('index','<u4'),('valid','b1')]`, and I have separate numpy arrays for the 32-bit `index` and boolean `valid` values, how can I do it?

I don't see a way in the numpy.ndarray constructor; I know I can do this:

```
arr = np.zeros(n, dtype = [('index','<u4'),('valid','b1')])
arr['index'] = indices
arr['valid'] = validity
```

but somehow calling `np.zeros()` first seems wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with filling in the 'columns' like this.  The only alternative is to give it a list of tuples, `[(i[0],v[0),(i[1],v[1])...]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is

```
arr = np.fromiter(zip(indices, validity), dtype=[('index','<u4'),('valid','b1')])
```

but I suspect your initial idea is more efficient.  (In your approach, you could use `np.empty()` instead of `np.zeros()` for a tiny performance benefit.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `empty` instead of `zeros`, and it should feel less 'wrong', since you are just allocating the data without unnecessarily zeroing it.

Or use `fromiter`, and pass in also the optional `count` argument if you're keen on performance.

This is in any case a matter of taste in more than 99% of the use cases, and won't lead to any noticeable performance improvements IMHO.